# REST API patch method URI having token mismatch in laravel

Tags: laravel, rest

I am trying to write a method in laravel 5.2 for the patch HTTP verb for REST, but it's showing a token mismatch. This is my `VerifyCsrfToken` class:

```php
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = ['v0.1/api/mc-api','v0.1/api/mc-api/{mc_api}'];
}
```

In my routes, I have the following:

```php
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'v0.1/api'),function(){
    Route::resource('mc-api','ApiController');
});

Route::any('v0.1/api/mc-api/*',['nocsrf'=>'true','uses'=>'ApiController@update']);
```

Based on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129497/discussion-between-ganesh-and-newbee-dev) I have tried changing my routes to the following but it doesn't help:

`Route::any('v0.1/api/mc-api/*',['nocsrf'=>true,'uses'=>'ApiController@update']);`

Nor does:

`Route::any('v0.1/api/mc-api/{mc_api}', 'ApiController@u‌​pdate');`

Comment: does it still throw that error after adding your routes to `VerifyCsrfToken`?

Comment: yes, it still throw that.

Comment: what's your current url?

Comment: localhost:8000/v0.1/api/mc-api/mc_api

Comment: can I see your routes?

Comment: PUT|PATCH | v0.1/api/mc-api/{mc_api}      | v0.1.api.mc-api.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@update       | web

Comment: try disabling your csrf by assigning false to your route
https://gyazo.com/ab5d36985a89a786cdc4549acbd4d3c3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129497/discussion-between-ganesh-and-newbee-dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class `VerifyCsrfToken` `$except` array

change

```
'v0.1/api/mc-api/{mc_api}'
```

to

```
'v0.1/api/mc-api/*'
```